# How to detach from a docker in a docker?

Tags: docker

Detaching from a docker container works with `CTRL-P + CTRL-Q`. However how do I detach from a docker in docker?

In my usecase I'm running ssh in a docker and on the server I also attach to docker containers. Now I would like to be able to detach from a conatiner I attached to on the server, however `CTRL-P + CTRL-Q` will detach from the local container running the ssh connection.

Is there any way to detach from the docker in the docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> twice will send a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to the container you are attached to.
So you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: @jasko Maybe ask a new question giving some details of your case?

Comment: @Brian, I already did but no one answered :) Eventually I figured out I need to attach container via 'exec' and then I can detach using 'exit'. Attaching with 'attach' does does not seem to be legit case for docker in docker.